# Optimizing ClickOnce Deployments: Streamlining Common DLLs in WPF Applications

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, clickonce

I have four different WPF applications that will be installed on a client's machine using the ClickOnce technique.

Each of these applications includes several common DLLs, such as DevExpress, Material Design, Aspose, and others, with a combined size of approximately 100+ MB.

Currently, each application downloads these common DLLs individually during the ClickOnce installation process. I am interested in creating an architecture resembling my own framework. This framework would be installed separately and would store these common DLLs on the client's machine. All the WPF applications could then utilize these shared DLLs from this common location. This approach aims to reduce the size of my WPF applications during installation, downloading, and automatic updates.

Can anyone guide me on correct direction to achieve this scenario?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are all four applications always being installed together? If so you could distribute them all as one application that installs in the same folder but uses different EXEs. Another option is to store the DLLs in a common location in Program Files but I doubt ClickOnce can accommodate a scenario like that. You'd probably need to be looking at InstallShield or something more on that level.

Comment: Some users may utilize only one of these features, while others may use all of them, and some might use two or three, depending on their specific roles and business requirements

Comment: Ok but are we talking about 4 different installers or 1 installer that provides all 4 applications to the same location? If you're committed to ClickOnce (or something similar) I think you're gonna be limited to the latter scenario. More professional/expensive tools will have more flexibility in terms of installing common files to common locations and giving users install options.

Comment: @EmperorEto  These are four different installer. I am committed to ClickOnce for auto updates and installation without any special windows privilege. Also those application are tied with different web module and it directly launch from web browser when needed using custom web protocols.

Comment: Ok then I don't think what you're looking to do is possible but maybe someone else has an idea.

Comment: @DarshanFaldu: Are you targeting the .NET Framework? Then you might be able to install your assemblies in the GAC on the target machines and exclude them from your ClickOnce applications. Or how and where is the application supposed to find these assemblies at runtime?

Comment: @mm8: Thank you. After conducting some preliminary research on Google, it seems that this approach is feasible. I will delve deeper into it and inform you of the final results. Thanks for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting the .NET Framework, you might be able to install your assemblies in the [Global Assembly Cache (GAC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) on the target machines and exclude them from your ClickOnce applications.

There is no concept of a global assembly cache in .NET Core and later versions of .NET though.

Comment: While this approach is suitable and can fulfill the requirements, the reason we initially opted for ClickOnce deployment is because it doesn't necessitate Windows administrator privileges for end users to install applications. Adding assemblies to the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) does require such privileges. Are there alternative methods, such as placing assemblies within specific folders (e.g., Documents, AppData, Roaming, etc.) and configuring these folders in the registry, that we can explore?

Comment: How should you be able to "configuring these folders in the registry" if you don't have sufficient privileges to install assemblies in the GAC? The end users should not install the assemblies in the GAC.

Comment: We can modify user-level registry settings without requiring Windows administrator privileges. In fact, we are already performing similar tasks. Yes I agree on modifying machine-level registry settings does require elevated privileges.